# how to grab a text from a certain div with jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for reading this..
I have the following html code

```
<div id="ImagePagination" class="Pagination"> 
    Photo 
    <span id="currentPhotoCount"><#currentPhotoCount#>
    </span> of
    <span id="maxPhotoCount"><#maxPhotoCount#>
    </span>
</div>​
```

The currentPhotoCount and maxPhotoCount variables are set from a jquery image slider script that works perfectly but i want to grab the text of the currentPhotoCount  so as to use it in an another script. Any suggestions of how i can achieve that will be highly appreciated!!!
I have tried this piece of code..am i doing something wrong?

```
  var pic=parseInt($('#currentPhotoCount').text(), 10);
  x = '../object_images/medium/<#OBJECT_ID#>_"'+pic+'".jpg';
  $(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").attr({src:x});
```

After hitting my head against the wall for several hours i realized that it was a quotes issue..I deleted the double quotes from the x variable so...

```
      x = '../object_images/medium/<#OBJECT_ID#>_"'+pic+'".jpg';
```

becomes

```
      x = '../object_images/medium/<#OBJECT_ID#>_'+pic+'.jpg';
```

And everything works as it should now...Thank you all very much for helping me!!

Comment: `$('#currentPhotoCount').text()` .. ?

Comment: Hiya - http://jsfiddle.net/EY3sR/ ?? :)  or http://jsfiddle.net/EY3sR/1/ cheers!

Comment: Why should it work, the text isn't a number...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#currentPhotoCount').text()
```

If you want the innerHTML:

```
$('#currentPhotoCount').html()
```

Comment: Infact i was doing the same thing but without success

Comment: @user926652 Probably should have shown any code you had previously tried, no one will be able to properly help otherwise.

Comment: I edited my post so you can see what i have tried nad tell me if it is wrong..thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you need the text as a string, just

```
$('#currentPhotoCount').text()
```

if you have to use that text as a number for further arithmetic operations (since it represents the current photo)

```
parseInt($('#currentPhotoCount').text(), 10);
```

Comment: I edited my post so you can see what i have tried nad tell me if it is wrong..thank you